# Need help in improving performance of SQL query

Tags: mysql

Take a look at this sqlfiddle i made http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b903/2/0. This is the simplified version of my database. I have a million records now in the history and the problem is that the query seems too slow. Sometimes it takes a minute to get the result. I'm not really good in this sql stuff. I guess there some columns that I need to index but Im not sure what are those.

update:

i tried to explain sql

```
id | select_type        | table | type  | possible_keys                                       | key               | key_len | ref          | rows  | Extra
1  | PRIMARY            | t1    | range | created_reason,created_reason_2                     | created_reason_2  | 6       | NULL         | 91136 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | t2    | ref   | history_table1_id_foreign,table1_id,table1_id_2     | table1_id_2       | 4       | t1.table1_id | 11    | Using where; Using index; Using filesort
```

Comment: Create indexes. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimization-indexes.html

Comment: Incidentally money is usually DECIMAL, not FLOAT

Comment: Also, you're using a correlated subquery. An uncorellated one is nearly always faster.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't created any indexes on any of the columns. Please read about linear and binary searches before you write heavy queries.

Add indexes to table1

```
alter table `test_delete`.`table1` 
add index `idx_created_at` (`created_at` asc),
add index `idx_price` (`price` asc);
```

Add indexes to history

```
alter table `test_delete`.`history` 
add index `idx_history_created_at` (`created_at` asc),
add index `idx_history_price` (`price` asc),
add index `idx_table1_id` (`table1_id` asc);
```

A minor change - won't have much effect

```
select t1.* from history t1 where t1.created_at >= '2016-03-13 00:00:00'
and t1.created_reason = 'Scraped'
and t1.price not in (-1, (
         select t2.price
           from history t2
          where t2.table1_id = t1.table1_id
            and t2.created_at  < t1.created_at
            and t2.created_at  > t1.created_at + interval -30 day
            and t2.price > -1
          order by t2.created_at desc
          limit 1
       ))
group by t1.table1_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can create the clustered index for following columns 
(`id` , `table1_id,`created_reason`,`created_at`timestamp,`updated_at`timestamp,`deleted_at` timestamp);

Then instead of sub query put those result  set into temp table and try to join with that temp table and main table.